# Building IIS Redirect Rule to Redirect Product Page to New URL Passing Product ID

Tags: regex, redirect, iis

I'm attempting to use the URL Rules engine in IIS 7 to redirect our current product pages to our new product pages.

Old Pages:

```
example.com/itemform.aspx?item=X12878
example.com/itemform.aspx?item=Y87304&showmenu=T
```

New URL

```
example.com/c/product/X12878
example.com/c/product/Y87304
```

#### Attempt

```
<rule name="Product Page Redirect">
  <match url="/itemform\.aspx\?item=([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://newsite.com/x/product/{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

#### Complete Rewrite Rule w/ Suggestion by Emma

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>           
    <rule name="Product Page Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="/itemform\.aspx\?item=([A-Za-z0-9.]+)" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://newsite.com/x/product/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoridng to your description, if you want to use url rewrite to get the right query string.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
            <rule name="QueryStringRue" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="itemform.aspx" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^item=([0-9a-zA-Z]*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/c/product/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This seems closer and it's redirecting me now but the product id isn't being appended to the redirect URL.

Comment: Nevermind... looks like this is working but the redirected site was failing on the page load.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe removing the end `$` anchor might simply make the match valid:

```
<rule name="Product Page Redirect">
  <match url="/itemform\.aspx\?item=([A-Za-z0-9.]+)" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://newsite.com/x/product/{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

but, maybe not.

Comment: The IIS Test Pattern tool is showing a successful match for those patterns after applying your fix but the pages still won't redirect.  Argh.